# Remove special chars from a File

Tags: c#, character-encoding, special-characters, text-files

I'm trying to open a textfile and remove all the special chars ñ Ñ ' á í etc...

the file its a Layout that the clients send to me and i parse it to send the file to an AS400 server but i have to remove all special chars.

THE PROBLEM IS:

some files with some special chars when i open it in c# it read the special chars and Two different chars and move the entire line one space to the right and then the information that has to be in that position wont be OK.

i take the same file and open it in Notepad and the file is OK but when i open it in WordPad it looks like 2 chars (for just 1 especial char) Example: in the file i have:

"0001   0003JUAN PEÑA33441JPENATEST"

But in c# it shows

"0001   0003JUAN PEï░A33441JPENATEST"

im using the encoding 1251

any help?

Comment: Are your clients required to send you files in encoding 1251? If so, are they doing so?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. I don't know what encoding types are supported by either Notepad or Wordpad, but how these applications display your file may not be important. What do you mean by "But in C# it shows..."? Do you mean in Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution to know the Encoding of a file.

Read the next link:

http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=469

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:
Reading the file and removing the chars.

You need to read the file in the encoding that is written:

```
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("YOUR FILE ENCODING"));
```

To remove the chars, you can try do it by hand...
Here is the code:

```
private static string CHAR_REPLACE_SRC = "áàãâÁÀÃÂéèêÉÈEíìîÍÌÎóòõôÓÒÕÔúùûÚÙÛçÇñÑ";
private static string CHAR_REPLACE_DST = "aaaaAAAAeeeEEEiiiIIIooooOOOOuuuUUUccnN";


private static string GetCleanString (string src)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < src.Length)
    {
        if (src[i] < 32 || src[i] > 127)
        {
            int pos = CHAR_REPLACE_SRC.IndexOf(src[i]);
            if (pos >= 0)
                src = src.Replace(CHAR_REPLACE_SRC[pos], CHAR_REPLACE_DST[pos]);
            else
                src = src.Remove(i, 1);
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    return src.Replace("\"", "").Replace("?", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("&", "_").Replace("\\", "_").Replace("/", "_");
}
```

You will probably need to do some adaptations.
I am using this to create a clean URL from the title of the page.